# Mac OS: In-App Purchase Error Code 0

Tags: objective-c, ios, in-app-purchase, osx-lion

I have unpleasant situation with testing in-app purchase in my Mac OS Application:

I created a new test user in iTunes Connect, subscribed receipt for the new build with this user, then purchased some product in my application shop using this test user account in sandbox mode and finally got the state `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` in the `updatedTransactions` method for my product-transaction.

Seems all is ok. Product ID for each product is valid, all products are in state `In Review` in iTunes Connect. This way I can successful buy all my products.

But it works only once.
In my shop I got consumable and non-consumable products.

When I reset purchases in my application shop and try to buy some product again with the same test user account.

For non-consumable products I must get `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored` state and for consumable I get `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` again.

But for all I get an error with `code 0` in the `updatedTransactions` method.

And with this test user I can't buy nothing else anymore more.

If I create new test user and repeat first part of my actions I again can successful buy all products in shop, but again only once. Trying to solve this problem for more than one day. So if someone has similar situation or have any ideas about solution, will be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is on the Apple side. After registration of a new app with new bundle and app id, all is ok with in app purchase, although code is the same. My version of this situation is that my first version of the app has been registered when there were no in-app purchase in Mac OS and when I add it to the new version of application some conflicts have appeared.